# Map the time in a Xarray dataset at which first occurrence of a value occurs

Tags: python, python-xarray

My xarray dataset looks like this:

```
xarray.DataArray 'mass' (time: 86, y: 115, x: 132)>
array([[[0.        , 0.        , 0.        , ..., 0.        ,
         0.        , 0.        ],
        [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , ..., 0.        ,
         0.        , 0.        ],
        [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , ..., 0.        ,
         0.        , 0.        ],
        ...,
        [7.86871581, 8.03121152, 8.1963989 , ..., 8.52833785,
         8.34455418, 8.16493449],
        [7.71566969, 7.87296236, 8.03278228, ..., 8.34824074,
         8.1713868 , 7.99838556],
        [7.56522864, 7.71749057, 7.87212488, ..., 8.17195143,
         8.00172886, 7.83507221]]])
Coordinates:
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 2021-09-19 2021-09-20 ... 2021-12-13
    band     int64 1
  * y        (y) int64 3161827 3161927 3162027 ... 3173027 3173127 3173227
  * x        (x) int64 213152 213252 213352 213452 ... 226052 226152 226252
```

The variable describes the cumulative accumulation of volcanic ash on the ground during an eruption and is monotonically increasing from a value of 0. For each pixel, I need to get the time at which the variable first exceeds a mass>=1, and return a data array of size (time: 1, y: 115, x: 132) that contains this date at each pixel.

I can imagine a way of doing it with a loop along the `time` dimension, but is there a more elegant and optimised way of doing so? Apologies if the question is naive, but conceptually I am stuck on how to convert coordinates into a variable.

Here is a [link to the data](https://kdrive.infomaniak.com/app/share/250506/c1f8a958-edda-4d00-98ea-236a74de493e).

### Update 1

I found a way using `da.where` and `da.idxmin`:

```py
da.where(da>=1).idxmin(dim='time')
```

However, this created a conflict in the data types:

```
TypeError: The DTypes <class 'numpy.dtype[int64]'> and <class 'numpy.dtype[datetime64]'> do not have a common DType. For example they cannot be stored in a single array unless the dtype is `object`.
```

The workaround I found was to assign a number of days since `t0` in int type as the `time` coordinate. Any advice on how to make this more elegant is still welcome!

### Full traceback

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~/Documents/WORK/Projects/La Palma/Isopach/interpolate_isopach_lapalma_splines.py in <module>
----> 1 da['thickness'].where(da['thickness']>=1).idxmin(dim='time').plot()

~/.conda/envs/volcgis/lib/python3.9/site-packages/xarray/plot/plot.py in __call__(self, **kwargs)
    444 
    445     def __call__(self, **kwargs):
--> 446         return plot(self._da, **kwargs)
    447 
    448     # we can't use functools.wraps here since that also modifies the name / qualname

~/.conda/envs/volcgis/lib/python3.9/site-packages/xarray/plot/plot.py in plot(darray, row, col, col_wrap, ax, hue, rtol, subplot_kws, **kwargs)
    197     kwargs["ax"] = ax
    198 
--> 199     return plotfunc(darray, **kwargs)
    200 
    201 

~/.conda/envs/volcgis/lib/python3.9/site-packages/xarray/plot/plot.py in newplotfunc(darray, x, y, figsize, size, aspect, ax, row, col, col_wrap, xincrease, yincrease, add_colorbar, add_labels, vmin, vmax, cmap, center, robust, extend, levels, infer_intervals, colors, subplot_kws, cbar_ax, cbar_kwargs, xscale, yscale, xticks, yticks, xlim, ylim, norm, **kwargs)
    746         _ensure_plottable(xplt, yplt, zval)
    747 
--> 748         cmap_params, cbar_kwargs = _process_cmap_cbar_kwargs(
    749             plotfunc,
    750             zval.data,

~/.conda/envs/volcgis/lib/python3.9/site-packages/xarray/plot/utils.py in _process_cmap_cbar_kwargs(func, data, cmap, colors, cbar_kwargs, levels, _is_facetgrid, **kwargs)
    845     cmap_kwargs.update((a, kwargs[a]) for a in cmap_args if a in kwargs)
    846     if not _is_facetgrid:
--> 847         cmap_params = _determine_cmap_params(**cmap_kwargs)
    848     else:
    849         cmap_params = {

~/.conda/envs/volcgis/lib/python3.9/site-packages/xarray/plot/utils.py in _determine_cmap_params(plot_data, vmin, vmax, cmap, center, robust, extend, levels, filled, norm, _is_facetgrid)
    229         # kwargs not specific about divergent or not: infer defaults from data
    230         divergent = (
--> 231             ((vmin < 0) and (vmax > 0)) or not center_is_none or levels_are_divergent
    232         )
    233     else:

TypeError: The DTypes <class 'numpy.dtype[int64]'> and <class 'numpy.dtype[datetime64]'> do not have a common DType. For example they cannot be stored in a single array unless the dtype is `object`.
```

### Reproduce error

Using [this file](https://kdrive.infomaniak.com/app/share/250506/815381d2-00ad-43ab-ae4d-175bf64a98ec) as `da.nc`.

```py
import xarray as xr

da = xr.open_dataset('~/Desktop/tmp/da.nc')
da = da.rename({'__xarray_dataarray_variable__':'thickness'})

da['thickness'].where(da['thickness']>=1).idxmin(dim='time').plot()
```

### Fragment of code

Where `da` is the data array shown above - just showing here how I interpolate through time as this is perhaps where something wrong happens.

```py
# Compute cumulative sum
da = da.cumsum(dim='time')

# Setup date
date = ['2021-09-19','2021-10-11','2021-11-26','2021-12-13']
date = pd.DataFrame(date,columns=['time'])
date['time'] = pd.to_datetime(date['time'])

# Interpolate to daily rates
dateD = date.set_index('time').resample('d').sum().reset_index()
da = da.interp(time=dateD['time'])

# Convert to dataset and remove the "band" dimension
da = da.drop_vars("band")
DA = da.to_dataset(name='thickness').squeeze()
```

Comment: This is weird  - it should work. Does this work if you first drop band, e.g. with `da = da.drop_vars("band")`?

Comment: Nope, still getting the same error. I initially thought it cam from the fact that not all pixels are expected to exceed this value, but does that don't show up as `NaT`, and the array shows up as `dtype='datetime64[ns]`.

Comment: Can you show all of your code and the full traceback?

Comment: Can you please tell me if what I added is enough?